# Create objects out of wsdl in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm originally Java developer, still baby stepping in .Net so please don't get take my question as a stupid one. I'm asked to use a pre-done Web Services. The Resources that was given to me doesn't include WS URL. I only have some documentations of the WS and its WSDL  http://beta.catcombinator.com/tracking-ws/api/gadget?wsdl
I know for sure that there is a tool in Java that can use this WSDL like JAXB to create objects out of WSDL, but I have no clue what to do in .NET to do such thing. Can you guys give me some support? PTW this WSDL is suppose to return a webservice and a Bean.
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [WSDL to Proxy Class Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generate your proxy classes from your WSDL.

Open a "Visual Studio command prompt", then it can be as simple as running the following command

```
svcutil http://beta.catcombinator.com/tracking-ws/api/gadget
```

Obviously, there are lots of command-line flags you might want to use to modify the output for language (c#, VB), namespace, etc.

To open the correct command prompt:

- Start → All Programs → Microsoft Visual Studio [Version] -> Visual Studio Tools

Comment: I've tried the command and it gave me error document understood butcouldnot be processed, BTW I'm using C#

Comment: also it says no connection could be made because the target machine activly refused it 127.0.0.1:8088

Comment: I might have given it slightly wrong - I can't test it because our proxy is blocking it. Try it again, without the `?wsdl` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Import the web service into Visual Studio**

In the right hand side of your project you have "References". You want to right-click on the "References" option and select "Add Web Reference". You will then be provided with a wizard for selecting the location of your WSDL file. Through this wizard visual studio will create a "Proxy" class for you so you can treat the web service as an object as you would in Java.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

[image]